# How to type & and # inside ///texttt{}?

Tags: urls

I am citing manually in TexStudio and trying to add a link to the patent I cited in my thesis. I get by adding this line:

```latex
\\\texttt{https://depatisnet.dpma.de/DepatisNet/depatisnet?action=bibdat{\&}docid=DE202015008958U1{\&}zd=1#zd}
```

The following mistakes:

1. Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a. ...dat{&}docid=DE202015008958U1{&}zd=1#zd}
2. You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode. ...dat{&}docid=DE202015008958U1{&}zd=1#zd}

I also tried $&$ but no avail.
Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The issue isn't `\&`, that one is correctly escaped. The issue is the `#` at the end. You should use `\#` there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you didn't escape `#`, which is the macro parameter token. Instead of using `#` directly, you should use `\#` there.

But there is a simpler alternative: Use the `url` package, you don't need to escape `&` and `#` and it will also apply line breaking automatically.

Compare the following two inputs, the first being the correctly escaped `\texttt` variant, the second the one using `\url`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{url}

\begin{document}
\texttt{https://depatisnet.dpma.de/DepatisNet/depatisnet?action=bibdat\&docid=DE202015008958U1\&zd=1\#zd}

\url{https://depatisnet.dpma.de/DepatisNet/depatisnet?action=bibdat&docid=DE202015008958U1&zd=1#zd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the /url is a way better solution. Thank you so much! @Skillmon

Comment: the `xurl` package might be even better as it will break the URL at any char.